# Dynamically load bootstrap pills content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

So I got 1000 images in my website, each 10 of them inside a different nav-pill, 100 pills in total. Thing is currently the whole 1000 images are loaded after entering the site and I think that will generate too much unnecessary traffic. What I want is (obviously) to load only the images inside the pill I have clicked/active. Why would I want to preload 1000 images when I only can see 10 of them? These guys of Bootstrap don't think it too much I guess.

Current code

```
     .tab-content(style="height:400px; overflow:auto")
       #menuflamenco.tab-pane.fade
         -for (i in flamenco){  
          img#flamenco(src='./img/paisaje/' + flamenco[i], style='width:300px;height:300px')
          -}  
       #menutoro.tab-pane.fade
         -for (i in toro){  
          img#toro(src='./img/paisaje/' + toro[i], style='width:200px;height:200px;')
          -}
```